# node js app deployed to heroku cant insert data to postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

Monika39_makerToday at 2:37 PM
hi, I have created a website using html, css, node.js and postgresql. it has a page that has html form. it worked well in my computer. all the data submitted in the form were successfully being saved to postgresql. then i deployed it in heroku. but now, the form is not sending the data to database. it keeps giving error 42703 which i think is because it is failing to insert data. i have also put the files in github https://github.com/Monika39-maker/school.github.io
GitHub
Monika39-maker/school.github.io

the heroku link https://ancient-shore-24857.herokuapp.com/html/admission.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To get the best answers for your question, please [edit] it to include the text of the code that fails, and the error message you get if any. You can indent code four spaces to format it correctly,. SO serves as a searchable archive of questions and their answers, so the questions need to have the details in them, not on some other site.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a connection issue in the dataabse.  Try using `DATABASE_URL` instead of passing the credentials one by one for the database connection:

```
const db = knex({
  // connect to your own database here
  client: 'pg',
  connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
});
```

Comment: Thank you. it turned out that i had spelling mistake in one of the column name. so embrassing!!